# Use locally deployed Alloy-UI

Tags: alloy-ui

I've started using Alloy UI by using CDNs at http://cdn.alloyui.com/3.0.0/aui/aui-min.js.

Is it possible to use Alloy UI locally without having to connect with the CDNs?  So install something locally which serves the required files. We'd like to do this so we don't have any external dependencies, for instance if our external internet connection is disabled we'd still like to use our internal apps which may rely on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is grab [the latest release of AlloyUI (`3.0.1`)](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/releases/download/3.0.1/alloy-3.0.1.zip)*, unzip it, and include it in your page like so:

```
<script src="/path/to/alloy-3.0.1/build/aui/aui-min.js"></script>
```

You may also want to include bootstrap similarly:

```
<link src="/path/to/alloy-3.0.1/build/aui-css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

There's a more in depth guide [here](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/working-with-the-alloyui-project-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) if you need it.

<sup>*For other releases of AlloyUI see [the releases page](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/releases).</sup>

Comment: That's great thanks!  Do you know if the src folder of files is required to run AlloyUI or do we just need to include the build folder?

Comment: I believe that you only need the code under the **`build/`** folder. You can examine [the AlloyUI zip included with Liferay Portal](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-web/third-party/alloy-3.0.1.zip) to see what code must be included to use AlloyUI.